# How to reduce the space between four buttons in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating a simple menu at the top of my web page using bootstrap 3, with btn and btn-info classes in four divs (col-md-3). the space between the buttons is too high. how can i reduce the space between them ? for example 5 pixels margin. it's my code :

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-info">
پشتیبانی
</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-info">
آموزش نصب آی او اس ۹
</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-info">
آموزش به دست آوردن یودید
</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-info">
خانه
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

you can see the web site at : ios9.siblearn.ir

Comment: I wouldn't use the grid for creating a menu. Instead you should have all those buttons in the same div and use `display:inline-block;` (which is actually the default display property for buttons in Bootstrap so you don't need to do anything in the CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tip for the future, [bootply.com](http://bootply.com) is better for mocking up Bootstrap issues since it has the Bootstrap framework included by default. Here is how I would set it up:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-info">
      پشتیبانی
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-info">
      آموزش نصب آی او اس ۹
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-info">
      آموزش به دست آوردن یودید
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-info">
      خانه
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/67yuZM01JS)